# How do you find out what versions of gradle is used in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In the build.gradle files, sometimes (I'm not sure when) you'll have to specify what version of gradle is used.  The last few updates of Android Studio kept breaking some build files which listed the gradle version in use.  I would have to update the gradle version number to fix the build file.  I wanted to know if there's a way to figure out what version of gradle is included with Android Studio, instead of having to guess.  I haven't been able to find out how to do this through Android Studio.

Comment: Read the release notes: http://tools.android.com/recent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can navigate to `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\wrapper\dists` and you can see which gradle versions have been downloaded

Comment: Thanks for that!  I'm using Ubuntu so the directories are slightly different.  For linux, it's in ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/ which is pretty much the same.  Quick question, I'm guessing that 1.12 means 0.12 in the build files?  Also, I have 5 directories, so I'm assuming that I can use all of them, with different gradle versions?

Comment: You're mixing up two things: gradle and gradle plugin. 1.12 is the version of gradle itself, whilst 0.12 is the version of gradle plugin. In build files you only specify gradle plugin version.

Comment: Ok, thanks Damian.  That clears up a lot since it's not clear from the build files that they're referring to the plugin, and not the actual gradle version.

Comment: Which raises the question, how do you figure out what version of the gradle plugin do you have?  I know someone earlier mentioned to read the release notes, but it's not there (or is buried a few links deep) and the latest version didn't have any release notes on the site.  Really, there should be a more direct way to figure out this info from looking somewhere on your machine instead of relying on some release note which may or may not be outdated/exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gradle wrapper then you can change (or just check) gradle version number in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. In order to do this you have to modify `distributionUrl`

Comment: I have no idea what gradle wrapper is.  How can you tell if you're using gradle wrapper?  I'm just using the standard Android Studio IDE, that I downloaded from Google, and updated using the update mechanism.  Does that setup use gradle wrapper?  I don't really touch gradle, and I suspect many others are in the same boat that I'm in.

Comment: When you create/import project you have to decide if you would like to use standalone gradle installation or gradle wrapper. When you choose first option you have to specify gradle path and manually manage gradle version. In the second case you can use graddle wrapper which is responsible for downloading gradle version specified in gradle-wrapper.properties config. It's very convienient when e.g. when you're building your project on CI server and you want to be sure that specific gradle version is used.

Comment: I just created a new app in Android Studio and it never gave me a choice between standalone or gradle wrapper.  In fact, the wizard didn't have anything to do with gradle, except at the end after creating the project, when it put up a notice about gradle finishing.  I hope you understand that the way gradle is handled by Android Studio can be very confusing.

Comment: I must have mixed something up. If I remember correctly there is such choice when you import existing project. In case you're creating new project I suppose the default is to use gradle wrapper.